# Regular expression and trailing slash

Tags: php, regex

I have this regular expression in PHP with the preg_match/preg_replace functions:

```
/test\/([A-Za-z]+)\/([A-Za-z]+)\/?([A-Za-z]+)?\/?/

=>

test/\1_\2/\3/
```

What I want is, that if it only says `http://domain.com/test` then it doesn't matter wheter there is a trailing slash or not - how do I do that?

EDIT:

I am doing this:

I have this array:

```
$routing = array(
    '/test\/([A-Za-z]+)\/([A-Za-z]+)\/?([A-Za-z]+)?\/?/' => 'test/\1_\2/\3/',

    '/error\/([0-9]+)/' => 'error/error_\1',
    '/sitemap\.html/' => 'sitemap',
    '/search\/([^\/]+)?/' => 'search/view/$1',
);
```

What I do is, that I perform this action to route the URL:

```
global $routing;

foreach ( $routing as $pattern => $result ) {
    if ( preg_match( $pattern, $url ) ) {
        return preg_replace( $pattern, $result, $url );
    }
}

return ($url);
```

My framework is doing this in the routing:

E.g. the url can be 
    test/stack/hello/21 
which is = to 
    Test::stack_hello(21)

So the set up is actually:
controller/func/tion/parameter = function/func_tion/parameter.

Comment: I suggest you change the first and last character to something else. That way, you won't have to escape all `/` chars.

Comment: It has to end with a slash else it will end up with a parse error? :)

Comment: It doesn't have to: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: So I can actually use # instead? I didn't know - thanks a lot.. Let's see if I can solve my question my self - but if you have any solutions or ideas then I hop, you post :-) thanks in advance

Comment: edit: nvm, misunderstood question.

Comment: There is nobody with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
$regex = '#test(?:/([a-z]+))(?:/([a-z]+))(?:/([a-z]+))/?$#i';
```

This matches a string that contains test, followed by a / and a series of letters, then that pattern is repeated twice more. The last character of the string to match is an optional / (and then the string should end because of the $). The pattern is repeated three times because that's the only way all three matches can be used as replacement patterns.

```
$text = 'test/abc/de/f';
$replacement = 'test/\1_/\3/\2/'; // de and f should switch places
var_dump(preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $text));
```

That shows the string `test/abc_/f/de/`

Comment: And how can it be matched on "the other side" ?

Can i re-use 'admix/\1_\2/\3/' ??? :-)

Comment: @Dennis: Are you talking about the replacment string by any chance? If so, update the question to clear that up, and show your current preg_replace call.

Comment: I am getting this error: Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier ')' when I use you your solution. I will update my question so it is more explicit what the problem is :) thanks

Comment: I am not sure I understand why you make 2 and 3 switch places?

Comment: Just for testing, so I could see more easily that the replacement actually takes place. I wanted the difference to be more than just the _ that's added.

Comment: Well, well, well.. The problem is, that currently all 3 parameters HAS to be set .. It isn't necessary!

E.g. the url can be test/stack/hello/21 = Test::stack_hello(21)

So the set up is actually:
controller/func/tion/parameter = function/func_tion/parameter.